# It's not winter, why "Winter Bash"

Tags: discussion

It's the middle of summer, it's very hot and humid, it's not winter!

SA is confused again?

Comment: :-) About 88 to 90% of the word's population lives in the northern hemisphere.

Comment: It's not only hemisphere related, but also cultural. Here (in my northern hemisphere cultural area) winter begins on the winter solstice (moreless today: dec/22). So, it was not winter when *Winter Bash* begun. :-)

Comment: Oops! It's only winter solstice in the northern hemisphere. To say it in a non-localized way we should call it [*Southern Solstice*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Southern_solstice).

Comment: @SAJ14SAJ I thought only regions with temperate climates experienced a winter season (about 40% of the world population). If that is correct then I would estimate only 35-36% of the world population considers it winter right now.

Comment: @ChrisSteinbach In the sense of cold weather and snow and such--yes; in the astronomical sense, its the hemisphere, although you could argue that seasons are insignificant inside the lines of tropics.

Comment: In New Delhi it was 5 degree Celcious in the morning today. Summers you say??

Comment: This is a question for the [network Meta](http://meta.stackoverflow.com), not Cooking Meta. Winter Bash is being held across SE.

Comment: @JoshCaswell Funny enough, there they've solved our problem with most of the world's population, winter climate seasons or so: [It's not winter in Saint Helen](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/159388/summer-in-saint-helena)

Comment: @J.A.I.L.: Indeed; can't we commemorate winter even if we're not currently experiencing it? Personally, I'm just looking forward to the upside-down hat bash that McCannot suggests there.

Comment: @JoshCaswell: That "network meta" concept died over a year ago, there were official announcements about it. Please - and this goes for everyone - don't redirect anyone to SO meta unless there's already an existing question there.

Comment: @Aaro[nu|bo]t: That's simply not true. The divvying up of content from Meta.SO into StackExchange-wide and SO-specific domains [was brought up by Jeff](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/124015/) most recently this past spring and is [status-planned]. It [is on indefinite hold](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/158652/159251), yes, but questions which affect the whole network are still [best placed on meta.stackoverflow.com](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/142134/).

Comment: @JoshCaswell No need. Most people never need to know about the "network meta" and can happily use just one SE site and its meta. (And we monitor child metas, so if an employee needs to weigh in on something, either we'll see it or mods can give us a shout if we miss something.)

Answer (score 1):

"Winter Where We Are Bash" just doesn't have quite the same ring to it. ;)

Beyond that, Aarthi covers it well [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/159397/155160):

> 1. Stack Overflow/Exchange is based in New York City, which is in the Northern hemisphere and is currently (theoretically) enjoying a nice, New Englandy winter.
> 2. There's lots of hats that are summer (or at least non-winter) themed.

Comment: NYC is not part of New England, although I love the city, and am happy to share my weather with them.